# is communication of nodes in cluster a good usage of scala actors?

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I'm building a java/Scala app which would be deployed in hundreds of nodes in cluster.  I thought of the following idea.  Instead of building rest api for my services where nodes would communicate and query and do operations one on each other.  I'll simply use akka actors in this way one actor can send messages to others and this would save me from the whole process of managing rest api's and even discovery of nodes load balancing etc (although in don't have to be asynchronous).

Note I'm aware of the motivation to use actors as means for async programming instead of locks I just want to know if the use case I suggested is actually a good use case for Hakka actors or am I missing something thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [Akka Cluster](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/common/cluster.html)

Comment: @ghik thanks, I would like to know if its a good practice to use this framework in anyway where i just need a cluster and services in that cluster talking to each other, is it my best choice?  (multiple services each service talks to other services in my cluster, i don't necessarily need async services i don't mind though).